# How to delete a certain system stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, how is it possible to delete a system stored procedure?

I was looking to delete or disable the following system procedures `xp_regwrite` and `xp_regdeletevalue`

I know how to remove these in SQL Server 2000, but can't find the documentation on how to delete them in SQL Server 2008.

The question is, how can I either

1. delete them, or
2. disable both of the them?

Comment: use permissions/config, rather than deleting system stored procs!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily recommend deleting any system stored procedures without due consideration ... but I assume that's not a problem in your case.

Simply go into the SSMS GUI, Databases, System databases, master, Programmability, System Extended Stored Procedures, select these procedures and delete them.

A better approach might be to revoke "public" execute permissions.

Comment: is it not possible to disable either of them?

Comment: "Revoke permissions" effectively "disables" the stored procedure:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669058%28v=vs.90%29.aspx   http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1138/giving-and-removing-permissions-in-sql-server/

Comment: that's not disabling the function though is it? it can still be used by someone with sysadmin rights or even db_owner, which is not what i asked.

Comment: @codrgii - if you can't trust the *sysadmin*, you have far more worrisome issues than two stored procedures.

Comment: Did you actually try this? I presume no as SQL Server will not let you delete the procedures in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

i decided to go back to 2005 to get this solved, revoking permissions did not help in my case and i wasn't willing to delete procedures that i would most likely need in the future.

Comment: Make sure to ac cept your own answer, if you feel it is the best solution.